# EncodingException: Keycloak to Infinispan

Tags: encoding, keycloak, infinispan

I have configured Infinispan Cluster version 14.0 with Keycloak version 21.0.2-debian-11-r0 on EKS Cluster.
When I bring up Keycloak, I am seeing below error:

```
org.infinispan.commons.dataconversion.EncodingException: ISPN000492: Cannot find transcoder between 'application/x-protostream' to 'application/x-jboss-marshalling'
```

What can be the issue?
Why am I getting Encoding error using same encoding at both side?

I have used `application/x-jboss-marshalling` encoding in infinispan server and keycloak cache configs.

My remote-server configuration looks like

```
    <distributed-cache name="loginFailures" owners="2">
            <expiration lifespan="900000000000000000"/>
            <remote-store cache="loginFailures" xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:13.0"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          shared="true" segmented="false"
                          connect-timeout="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_CONN_TIMEOUT:2000}">
                <remote-server host="${env.INFINISPAN_SERVER}" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}"/>
                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <digest username="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_USERNAME:keycloak}"
                                password="${env.KEYCLOAK_REMOTE_ISPN_PASSWORD:password}"
                                realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>

                <property name="rawValues">true</property>
                <property name="marshaller">org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.KeycloakHotRodMarshallerFactory</property>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
```

Comment: Also I tried changing that to  `application/x-protostream` to at both side but getting below error:
`Caused by: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=1390 returned server error (status=0x84): javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05087: Client selected realm not offered by server (AllowScriptManager)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Keycloak does not support protostream as far as I know. Looking at the source code, you can find the default config here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/quarkus/runtime/src/main/resources/cache-ispn.xml. For the Infinispan server, you don't need to configure any encoding.

Comment: I want to set up around 1000 realms on Keycloak instance.. For that need to setup Keycloak with separate Infinispan Cache Cluster to improve the Keycloak performance.

Comment: I tried removing Protostream encoding as well.. but somehow I am getting this error
`ELY05087: Client selected realm not offered by server (AllowScriptManager)`

Comment: can you double-check your `<remote-store>` configuration? It seems the error is suggesting that the realm name in `<remote-store>` does not exist in the Infinspan server configuration.

Comment: I have added my remote-server configuration in my post.
After going through keycloak logs noticed this error:

`2023-04-10 15:05:27,621 DEBUG 
2023-04-10 15:05:27,626 WARN  [org.infinispan.HOTROD] (Thread-0) ISPN004005: Error received from the server: org.infinispan.commons.dataconversion.EncodingException: ISPN000495: ProtostreamTranscoder encountered error transcoding content
org.infinispan.protostream.MalformedProtobufException: Found an invalid protobuf tag (3) having a field number smaller than 1`

And similar error in one of infinispan pod.

Comment: can you share the cache configuration from the Infinispan server?

Comment: Thanks @pruivo for your response.
This issue got fixed after changing Keycloak image to: bitnami/keycloak:20.0.5-debian-11-r13
Previously I was using latest and it was taking something 21.0.5-debian...

Comment: However I am getting different issue in 20.0.5-debian-11-r13.
Admin console gets stuck for longer time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found fix for this. Ref: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/20031

Now Keycloak version 21 is working with Infinispan cache.